# Hadith that describes the conversation between Allah and the angels that namaz expiates sins

Tags: salat, hadith, allah, malaikah

Is there any hadeeth that states that allah commands the angels to set the sins of the person offering namaz aside, and then remove it permanently?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To make yourself familiar with our site and model I strongly recommend you to take our [tour] and check our [help]. Do you look for such a narration because you've heard something like that or what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

I have not come across a hadith that captures a conversation between Allah and the angels commanding them not to record the person's sins until the person had performed prayers, then to remove the sins permanently. However, there is a hadith with a similar conversation between the Prophet ﷺ and a companion of his as follows:

> حَدَّثَنِي عَبْدُ الْقُدُّوسِ بْنُ مُحَمَّدٍ، حَدَّثَنِي عَمْرُو بْنُ عَاصِمٍ الْكِلاَبِيُّ، حَدَّثَنَا هَمَّامُ بْنُ يَحْيَى، حَدَّثَنَا إِسْحَاقُ بْنُ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ أَبِي طَلْحَةَ، عَنْ أَنَسِ بْنِ مَالِكٍ ـ رضى الله عنه ـ قَالَ كُنْتُ عِنْدَ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم فَجَاءَهُ رَجُلٌ فَقَالَ يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ إِنِّي أَصَبْتُ حَدًّا فَأَقِمْهُ عَلَىَّ‏.‏ قَالَ وَلَمْ يَسْأَلْهُ عَنْهُ‏.‏ قَالَ وَحَضَرَتِ الصَّلاَةُ فَصَلَّى مَعَ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم فَلَمَّا قَضَى النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم الصَّلاَةَ قَامَ إِلَيْهِ الرَّجُلُ فَقَالَ يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ إِنِّي أَصَبْتُ حَدًّا، فَأَقِمْ فِيَّ كِتَابَ اللَّهِ‏.‏ قَالَ ‏"‏ أَلَيْسَ قَدْ صَلَّيْتَ مَعَنَا ‏"‏‏.‏ قَالَ نَعَمْ‏.‏ قَالَ ‏"‏ فَإِنَّ اللَّهَ قَدْ غَفَرَ لَكَ ذَنْبَكَ ‏"‏‏.‏ أَوْ قَالَ ‏"‏ حَدَّكَ ‏"‏‏
>
> Narrated Anas bin Malik: While I was with the Prophet (ﷺ) a man came and said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! I have committed a legally punishable sin; please inflict the legal punishment on me'.' The Prophet (ﷺ) did not ask him what he had done. Then the time for the prayer became due and the man offered prayer along with the Prophet (ﷺ), and when the Prophet (ﷺ) had finished his prayer, the man again got up and said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! I have committed a legally punishable sin; please inflict the punishment on me according to Allah's Laws." The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Haven't you prayed with us?' He said, "Yes." The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Allah has forgiven your sin," or said, "... your legally punishable sin."
>
> <sub>— [Sahih al-Bukhari, Book 86, Hadith 52](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6823)</sub>

There is another hadith which documents a conversation between Allah and the angels, but it does not specify prayers as the reason for not punishing the person; rather, it is repentance:

> حَدَّثَنِي عَبْدُ الأَعْلَى بْنُ حَمَّادٍ، حَدَّثَنَا حَمَّادُ بْنُ سَلَمَةَ، عَنْ إِسْحَاقَ بْنِ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ، بْنِ أَبِي طَلْحَةَ عَنْ عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنِ أَبِي عَمْرَةَ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، عَنِ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم فِيمَا يَحْكِي عَنْ رَبِّهِ عَزَّ وَجَلَّ قَالَ ‏"‏ أَذْنَبَ عَبْدٌ ذَنْبًا فَقَالَ اللَّهُمَّ اغْفِرْ لِي ذَنْبِي.‏ فَقَالَ تَبَارَكَ وَتَعَالَى أَذْنَبَ عَبْدِي ذَنْبًا فَعَلِمَ أَنَّ لَهُ رَبًّا يَغْفِرُ الذَّنْبَ وَيَأْخُذُ بِالذَّنْبِ.‏ ثُمَّ عَادَ فَأَذْنَبَ فَقَالَ أَىْ رَبِّ اغْفِرْ لِي ذَنْبِي.‏ فَقَالَ تَبَارَكَ وَتَعَالَى عَبْدِي أَذْنَبَ ذَنْبًا فَعَلِمَ أَنَّ لَهُ رَبًّا يَغْفِرُ الذَّنْبَ وَيَأْخُذُ بِالذَّنْبِ.‏ ثُمَّ عَادَ فَأَذْنَبَ فَقَالَ أَىْ رَبِّ اغْفِرْ لِي ذَنْبِي.‏ فَقَالَ تَبَارَكَ وَتَعَالَى أَذْنَبَ عَبْدِي ذَنْبًا فَعَلِمَ أَنَّ لَهُ رَبًّا يَغْفِرُ الذَّنْبَ وَيَأْخُذُ بِالذَّنْبِ وَاعْمَلْ مَا شِئْتَ فَقَدْ غَفَرْتُ لَكَ ‏"‏.‏ قَالَ عَبْدُ الأَعْلَى لاَ أَدْرِي أَقَالَ فِي الثَّالِثَةِ أَوِ الرَّابِعَةِ ‏"‏ اعْمَلْ مَا شِئْتَ ‏"‏
>
> Abu Huraira reported from Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) that his Lord, the Exalted and Glorious, thus said. A servant committed a sin and he said: "O Allah, forgive me my sins," and Allah (the Exalted and Glorious) said: "My servant committed a sin and then he came to realise that he has a Lord Who forgives the sins and takes to account (the sinner) for the sin." He then again committed a sin and said: "My Lord, forgive me my sin," and Allah, the Exalted and High, said: "My servant committed a sin and then came to realise that he has a Lord Who would forgive his sin or would take (him) to account for the sin." He again committed a sin and said: "My Lord, forgive me for my sin," and Allah (the Exalted and High) said: "My servant has committed a sin and then came to realize that he has a Lord Who forgives the sins or takes (him) to account for sin. O servant, do what you like. I have granted you forgiveness." 'Abd al-A'la said: I do not know whether he said on the third instance or the fourth instance to do "what you desire".
>
> <sub>— [Sahih Muslim, Book 50, Hadith 33](https://sunnah.com/muslim/50/33)</sub>

The general idea of your question is there in Islam. In the Qur'an, Allah commands the Prophet ﷺ and us to establish prayers as the good deeds erase the bad ones:

> وَأَقِمِ الصَّلَاةَ طَرَفَيِ النَّهَارِ وَزُلَفًا مِّنَ اللَّيْلِ إِنَّ الْحَسَنَاتِ يُذْهِبْنَ السَّيِّئَاتِ ذَٰلِكَ ذِكْرَىٰ لِلذَّاكِرِينَ
>
> And establish prayer at the two ends of the day and at the approach of the night. Indeed, good deeds do away with misdeeds. That is a reminder for those who remember.
>
> <sub>— [Surat Hud 11:114](https://quran.com/11/114)</sub>

This is a general concept, not specific to a person or a time or a place as documented in this hadith:

> حَدَّثَنَا يَحْيَى بْنُ يَحْيَى، وَقُتَيْبَةُ بْنُ سَعِيدٍ، وَأَبُو بَكْرِ بْنُ أَبِي شَيْبَةَ - وَاللَّفْظُ لِيَحْيَى - قَالَ يَحْيَى أَخْبَرَنَا وَقَالَ الآخَرَانِ، حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو الأَحْوَصِ، عَنْ سِمَاكٍ، عَنْ إِبْرَاهِيمَ، عَنْ عَلْقَمَةَ، وَالأَسْوَدِ، عَنْ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ، قَالَ جَاءَ رَجُلٌ إِلَى النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم فَقَالَ يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ إِنِّي عَالَجْتُ امْرَأَةً فِي أَقْصَى الْمَدِينَةِ وَإِنِّي أَصَبْتُ مِنْهَا مَا دُونَ أَنْ أَمَسَّهَا فَأَنَا هَذَا فَاقْضِ فِيَّ مَا شِئْتَ.‏ فَقَالَ لَهُ عُمَرُ لَقَدْ سَتَرَكَ اللَّهُ لَوْ سَتَرْتَ نَفْسَكَ - قَالَ - فَلَمْ يَرُدَّ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم شَيْئًا فَقَامَ الرَّجُلُ فَانْطَلَقَ فَأَتْبَعَهُ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم رَجُلاً دَعَاهُ وَتَلاَ عَلَيْهِ هَذِهِ الآيَةَ ‏{‏ أَقِمِ الصَّلاَةَ طَرَفَىِ النَّهَارِ وَزُلَفًا مِنَ اللَّيْلِ إِنَّ الْحَسَنَاتِ يُذْهِبْنَ السَّيِّئَاتِ ذَلِكَ ذِكْرَى لِلذَّاكِرِينَ‏}‏ فَقَالَ رَجُلٌ مِنَ الْقَوْمِ يَا نَبِيَّ اللَّهِ هَذَا لَهُ خَاصَّةً قَالَ ‏"‏ بَلْ لِلنَّاسِ كَافَّةً ‏"‏
>
> 'Abdullah reported that a person came to Allah's Apostle (ﷺ) and said: "Allah's Messenger, I sported with a woman in the outskirts of Medina, and I have committed an offense short of fornication. Here I am (before you), kindly deliver a verdict about me which you deem fit." 'Umar said: "Allah concealed your fault. You had better conceal it yourself also." Allah's Apostle (ﷺ) gave no reply. The man stood up and went away and Allah's Apostle (ﷺ) sent a person after him to call him and be recited this verse: "establish prayer at the two ends of the day and at the approach of the night. Indeed, good deeds do away with misdeeds. That is a reminder for those who remember." (XI:114). A person amongst the people said: "Allah's Apostle, does it concern this man only?" Thereupon he (the Holy Prophet) said: "No, but the people at large."
>
> <sub>— [Sahih Muslim, Book 50, Hadith 50](https://sunnah.com/muslim/50/50)</sub>